# publicar en aplicacion Rails en Heroku

Tags: heroku

estoy intentando subir mi aplicación a Heroku pero no me funcionan algunas imagenes, jquery y APIs que puede ser?, a alguien le ha pasado?

logs de Heroku:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Nunca hice un deploy con Ruby, solo con Angular.. pero viendo lo que te devuelve el logs, evidentemente tenés un error en las rutas(están mal definidas). Recuerda que cuando lo pasas a producción la URL 
para las API no es más 'localhost'